# Where are my small contributions in the FEC filings?

Tags: election, campaign-finance, fec

I know that I have made several small contributions over the last year, but only one of those contributions/transactions appears when I look at the FEC individual contributions dataset ([found here](https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data)) for this year.

I see that committees are required to [record small contributions](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/keeping-records/records-receipts/)

The [descriptions](https://www.fec.gov/campaign-finance-data/contributions-individuals-file-description/) for the present reads as follows:

> 2015 - present: greater than $200
>
> A contribution will be included if:
>
> The contribution’s election cycle-to-date amount is over $200 for contributions to candidate committees
>
> The contribution’s calendar year-to-date amount is over $200 for contributions to political action committees (PACs) and party
> committees.

There are a couple things I don't understand in that explanation, namely the use of *contributions* -- is this referring to "a single person's contributions".

I think I'm further confused because of the term "committee" - AFAIK that would mean either being a **PAC** or **individual candidate**.

So how come only one of my small contributions show up in the FEC filings?